# How to download PDF file from intranet in .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, download, response

Question as Title.

I want to have a button that click it will download the pdf file where the file is stored in the other intranet server.

I try to use the code below to download the pdf file from other intranet's file.

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.pdf")
Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("\\intranetServer\Test.pdf"))
Response.End()
```

I dont know it's code's problem or something else?

Maybe IIS need to set something config?

I have no idea to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the  **My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile**

For example you could do:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("\\intranetServer\Test.pdf","Path\Folder\file.pdf")
```

Otherwise you can use **System.Net.WebClient**

This will let you track progress and have more control for instance:

```
Dim wc As System.Net.WebClient
wc = New System.Net.WebClient()
wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("\\intranetServer\Test.pdf";), "Path\Folder\file.pdf")
```

PS: I'm not sure about the structure of the URI for intranet you might need `Net.Tcp://`

If you want to keep your solution try to use this and remember you need to make sure the IIS is visible to everyone and structure the Uri correctly might need to use the **file://** !

```
Private Sub WriteFile(filepath As String, fileName As String, contentType As String, response As HttpResponse)
    response.Buffer = True
    response.Clear()
    response.ContentType = contentType
    response.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
    response.HeaderEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")

    Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & fileName)

    response.WriteFile(filepath)
    response.Flush()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any possible to use stream and byte() to download? There is forbidden to make user access file directly.

Comment: @鄭有維 I have no idea at all as I'm not familiar with working with IIS. I would think that if the user access is forbidden then it wouldn't even be possible to stream it but I'm really not sure. Try using your stream to use the **file://** or the **Net.Tcp://** maybe that can help.

Comment: As far as I know, User can't access the file but user can access the sever and server can access the file and give back the file stream.